# I want to exclude a sub folder from a recursive search and copy

Tags: powershell

I want to look in directory "x" recursively for file type "y" excluding sub directory "m" and copy files to sub directory  "m"

im trying this

```
$TargetDir = read-host "Please enter target Dir"
$sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir" 
$format = read-host "Format to look for" 
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -Filter $format | where  FullName -Not -Like $TargetDir | 
Copy-Item -Destination $TargetDir
```

Comment: the `-like` operator is a _wildcard_ operator. you likely are not using any wildcard in your `$TargetDir`. when used without a wildcard character, the `-like` is equivalent to the `-eq` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You better try use `foreach` cycle. Here is example for searching for photo and video.

```
# Making an array of all files from Get-ChildItem
$searchItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -Include *.mp4,*.jpg,*.jpeg | where  FullName -notlike $TargetDir
# Copy files one by one in cycle
foreach($currentFile in $searchItems) {
  Copy-Item -Path $currentFile.Fullname -Destination $TargetDir
}
```

Comment: Alex R.  What would the variable $b indicate?

Comment: We have all search items in `$a` array. `foreach` help us to to work with all elements in array one by one. Every element will be in `$b` and you can work with it as is.

Comment: So the target dir is a sub dir from the source dir.  I am getting an error where its copying files already in the target dir bc the recursive.

Comment: As for this... [But it would be great to have some things explained CODE]... that what comment blocks are used for and you should always write your code in a complete native language verbose way. No shorthand, no single-letter variables, no run-on sentences/code lines, etc. For the most part, your code should be easy to read and follow, even the absolute novice, whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, But it would be great to have some things explained
CODE:

```
   $TargetDir = read-host "Please enter target Dir"
   $sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir"
   $format = read-host "Format to look for"
   $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -filter $format | Where 
   {($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($TargetDir -notcontains $_.Name)}
   foreach ($f in $folders){
   Write-Host "These Files will be copied: $f"
   Copy-Item - path $sourceDir$f -Destination $TargetDir\$f -Recure -Force}
```

I dont understand :

```
  Where {($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($TargetDir -notcontains $_.Name)}
```

and why

```
Write-Host "These Files will be copied: $f"
```

does not show up when ran

Answer (score 0):

This...

> [Write-Host "These Files will be copied: $f"]

... is because you are doing this is a loop, and Write-Host clear the buffer. Except for when you need colorized screen output, Write-Host is mostly useless. Well, except for in some formatting use cases. Generally just don't use it. Even the PowerShell author says so.

Output to the screen is the PowerShell default unless you tell it otherwise. The better option to Write-Host is Write-Output, or Out-Host or Tee-Object. See the help files on their particulars.

Get-ChildItem has several switches and if you just want directories, there's a switch for that and -Exclude for well, you know.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
...
Exclude
...
Directory --- (This is what that $_.PSIsContainer/$PSItem.PSIsContainer this is doing, but that is legacy stuff.)
...
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online
```

[About Objects --- Objects in Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_objects?view=powershell-7)

Thus...

```
# Get directory names only and return only the full UNC
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'D:\SourceFolder'-Recurse).FullName
# Results
<#
D:\SourceFolder\est
D:\SourceFolder\here
D:\SourceFolder\hold
D:\SourceFolder\TargetFolder
#>

# Just like the above, but exclude the TargetFolder
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'D:\SourceFolder' -Exclude 'TargetFolder' -Recurse).FullName
# Results
<#
D:\SourceFolder\est
D:\SourceFolder\here
D:\SourceFolder\hold
#>
```

So, a small refactoring of your code.

```
# Recursively get all text files, in all directories, except one for copy action
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\SourceFolder' -Filter '*.txt' -Exclude 'TargetFolder' -Recurse |
ForEach { 
    "These Files will be copied: $($PSItem.FullName)"

    # Remove the -whatIf for the actual run.
    Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination 'D:\SourceFolder\TargetFolder' -Recurse -WhatIf 
}
# Results
<#
These Files will be copied: D:\SourceFolder\here\mytest - Copy.txt
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\SourceFolder\here\mytest - Copy.txt Destination: D:\SourceFolder\TargetFolder\mytest - Copy.txt".
These Files will be copied: D:\SourceFolder\here\mytest.txt
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\SourceFolder\here\mytest.txt Destination: D:\SourceFolder\TargetFolder\mytest.txt".
These Files will be copied: D:\SourceFolder\hold\awél.txt
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\SourceFolder\hold\awél.txt Destination: D:\SourceFolder\TargetFolder\awél.txt".
#>
```

Of course, you need to tweak the above yo use your variables, and take out all the comments. Commenting is a good thing, but over commenting is just as bad as under commenting or bad/unintelligible commenting. All of which many have their preferences.

My rules:

1. Don't comment on the obvious, where the code speaks for itself.
2. Don't use shorthand stuff only you know or remember.
3. Write in the plain straight forward localized language.
4. Write for those that don't know you or shorthand stuff and will follow you or who may use/review your code; who can and often are new to this stuff.